# Convert Openweathermap Sunrise JSON value to NSDate IOS

Tags: ios, json, xml, nsdate, openweathermap

i'm working on a weather app for school and I don't understand at all how to read the sunrise value returned by the openweathermap API see below (we have to use JSON format) :

JSON :

```
  "sys":{  
     "sunrise":1418107981,
     "sunset":1418140433
  }
```

XML :

```
<sun rise="2014-12-09T06:52:59" set="2014-12-09T15:53:53"/>
```

the values are the same but in 2 different format ...

So my question is :

How can I convert this [ "sunrise":1418107981 ] into a NSDate object ?

---

Edit (Thanks to Hot Licks):

To make so

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1418107981];
NSLog(@"The Sunrise : %@", date);
date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1418140433];
NSLog(@"The Sunset  : %@", date);
```

Comment: It's a "UNIX epoch" date value -- seconds since Jan 1, 1970.  The necessary function to convert to NSDate is available if you look (carefully) at the NSDate documentation.

Comment: Ok I will look for it, if I found an answer I will edit my question with the answer :) thank you

Comment: I am building a weather app in JS not IOS. How do then convert sunrise":1418107981 to something like 16:45 EDT (new york)?

Comment: Use [Moment.js Library](http://momentjs.com/), by doing so : `var dateTimeString = moment(1439198499).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");` where 1439198499 is the unix date